Are there live versions of Bohemian Rhapsody with the prelude 'is this the real life ...'?
In the recording room version of Bohemian Rhapsody
there is a prelude:

Is this the real life?
Is it just fantasy?
Caught in a landslide
No escape from reality
Open your eyes
Look up to the skies and see
I'm just a poor boy, I need no sympathy
Because I'm easy come, easy go
Little high, little low
Anyway the wind blows,
Doesn't really matter to me,
to me.

I really like this chorus part. However, it seems it's skipped in live versions.
Are there any live versions including this prelude?
